# JTable get all rows that are being edited

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable which has 2 columns

- column 0 username
- column 1 password.

for the password column it will be encrypted to SHA256.

Basically what I want to achieve is it will update all the rows in my password column to SHA256 that I have edited after my button is pressed.

so..

I have a RowData class, this will store the text being edited and the position of the text
being edited(rows,columns).

```
public class RowData {
    int rows = 0, columns = 0;
    String text = " ";  
    public RowData(String text,int rows, int columns) {
        setEditedRows(rows);
        setEditedColumns(columns);
        setEditedText(text);
    }

    public int getEditedRows() {
        return rows;
    }

    public int getEditedColumns() {
        return columns;
    }

    public String getEditedText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setEditedRows(int rows) {
        this.rows = rows;
    }

    public void setEditedColumns(int columns) {
        this.columns = columns;
    }

    public void setEditedText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

I wrote a TableModelListener.. I have an List to store the text and the rows and columns
after the table has changed

```
 table.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
            @Override
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                int row = e.getFirstRow();
                int column = e.getColumn();
                TableModel model = (TableModel) e.getSource();
                //System.out.println(model.getValueAt(row, column));
                if(column == 1) {
                    String data = (String) model.getValueAt(row, column);
                    System.out.println(data);
                    dataList.add(new RowData(data,row,column));
                }

            }
        });
```

In my button I loop through the list and retrieve the rows, and columns and text
and set the password to SHA256 to the JTable.

```
updateBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (table.getCellEditor() != null) {
                table.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();    
                for(int i = 0; i < dataList.size(); i++) {
                    String text = dataList.get(i).getEditedText();
                    int rows = dataList.get(i).getEditedRows();
                    int columns =  dataList.get(i).getEditedColumns();
                    //System.out.println(dataList.get(i).getEditedText() + " " +  dataList.get(i).getEditedRows() + dataList.get(i).getEditedColumns());
                    table.setValueAt(convertPassword.convertToSHA256(text), rows ,columns);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

The result I get is I will keep printing the password endlessly in my console.
So I think that my logic is wrong and needed to be corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
table.setValueAt(convertPassword.convertToSHA256(text), rows ,columns);
```

When you change the TableModel the TableModelListener will be invoked again. The TableModelListener is invoked whether you change the data by using the JTable or by updating the TableModel directly.

The solution would be to remove the TableModelListener when you click on your button, at the start of your ActionListener. You would then need to add the TableModelListener back to the TableModel at the end of the code in case the user make further changes.

Another solution is to have 3 columns in the TableModel, username, password and sha256Password. Then you can use the JTable to display only the first two columns. See the `removeColumn()` method of JTable. Then your conversion code would update the TableModel using:

```
table.getModel().setValueAt(value, row, 2);
```

Now the code in your TableModel will be invoked, but because you check for updates to column 1, nothing will happen when you update column 2.

Then when you save the data you save the data from the TableModel.

Edit:

> I must click into another cell before I can press my button to edit.

You need to stop the cell editing. See [Table Stop Editing](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/12/table-stop-editing/) for a couple of solutions.

Comment: thanks. I noticed another problem. not sure if you can help me again.Now I clicked into the rows and edit. I must click into another cell before I can press my button to edit.

Comment: e.g I click into table[0][2] cell and edit first, I must click away into another click before I can press my update button. is there any way to resolve this?